# Button Foreground Disabled Color in Android (XAMARIN)

Tags: android, xamarin, colors, xamarin.android

I use control Button, for Android, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android ButtonRenderer.

On UWP I can easy change with xaml any color of standart button with one line:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundDisabled" Color="White"  />
```

Can I do it for Android?

Comment: I don't get it. Do you mean, you want to use `ButtonRenderer` with Xaml codes?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT yes, I have already done it)